# Cannot Send Message from Popup to Content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to send message from Popup.js into Content script by this code:

## popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { xpath: xpath });
});
```

And Receive it in Content Script by this code:

## content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage());

function gotMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert("Hello");
 
}
```

My Manifest is:

## manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Auto Clicker",
  "description": "Set Time, Set Element to Click, Start!",
  "version": "0.1",

  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon-16x16.png",
      "24": "images/icon-24x24.png",
      "32": "images/icon-32x32.png"
   },
   "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": [
         "<all_urls>"
       ],
       "js": ["content.js"]
     }
    ],
    "default_title": "Auto Clicker",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16x16.png",
    "24": "images/icon-24x24.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32x32.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128x128.png"
  }
}
```

Why it is not Working? the messages is'nt send to the Content script.

Comment: Your content script runs after DOMContentLoaded is fired in a web page so if you open the popup before that there'll be no content script yet. Either switch to [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#programmatic) instead of declaring the script in manifest.json, or use ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time). Also note, chrome UI pages (including the new tab page) don't run content scripts at all.

Comment: Can you more explain about a programmatic injection? please provide with my code @wOxxOm

Comment: See the documentation article I've linked.

Comment: Another example: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: Thank you I manage it by IFFE Function :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved in this way:

```
// Inject Trigger to the current active Web Page
function injectTheScript() {
  let xpath = document.getElementById("xpath-input").value || "";
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: `
      (function () {
        let btn = new XPathEvaluator()
        .createExpression("${xpath}")
        .evaluate(document, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue;
        btn.click();
       })();
      `
    });
 });
}
```